# How can I simulate typing text? Javascript/jQuery, vextab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I'm using a javascript package called vextab. https://github.com/0xfe/vextab
The package makes creating guitar tabs in javascript easy.
Refer to this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hy8efjg4/

The package loads the tab svg based on the div attributes and contents.
I want to be able to change the contents of the div to render new tab svgs.
How can I do this?

```
<div class="vextab-auto"
    width=680 scale=1.0 editor="true"
    editor-width=680 editor-height=330>
    options space=20
    tabstave notation=true key=A time=4/4

    notes :q =|: (5/2.5/3.7/4) :8 7-5h6/3 ^3^ 5h6-7/5 ^3^ :q 7V/4 |
    notes :8 t12p7/4 s5s3/4 :8 3s:16:5-7/5 :h p5/4
    text :w, |#segno, ,|, :hd, , #tr

    options space=25
</div>

# javascript

scratch_tab = "options space=40 font-size=14\n" +
                  "tabstave notation=true key=A\n" +
                  "notes :q (5/2.5/3.7/4) $A7#9$ 15h16/1 20/1"

$('.editor').val(scratch_tab);
$('.editor').keyup();
```

That keyup is there to show that even triggering a keyup won't help.

Comment: This is a nice animation https://codepen.io/freedom8/pen/BjbPVg

Comment: this doesn't help me at all.

Comment: @MikeJohnson Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. complete HTML to test it. Please also provide expected output, e.g. in the form of a simple animated gif (to see what you are after, because the comment from Jens seemed exactly what you are asking for..)

Comment: Please take a look at this example too: https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/yyprGq

Answer (score 0):

used the API to achieve the desired results (their native js package, not browser -- but it still works in the browser)